# Was this how the Knights Of Ren were formed?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*, Luke discusses what happened between him and Kylo Ren:

> I can't remember his exact words, but Luke basically says that after their confrontation, Ben Solo left, **taking some of Luke's students with him** and killing the others.

Were these people the ones who eventually became the Knights Of Ren?

I've not read any of the novelisations or other books, so apologies if this has already been covered in those sources.

Comment: The Knights of Ren are speculated to be the *Acolytes of the Beyonf*

Comment: the exact words are: "When I came to, the temple was burning. He had vanished with a handful of my students... slaughtered the rest".

Comment: The novelization isn't out until March--I don't know if TLJ visual dictionary has an update on them?

In additon there was extensive reporting early on that now suggest that there may have been more TKOR scenes cut from the film. RJ says they will not release an extended cut, but there may be a lot of deleted scenes on the blu-ray edition.

Comment: @Edlothiad, the force vision(s) in TLJ may suggest they are not the same, but there are still a lot of things we don't know about this whole arrangement between Snoke and TKOR.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think an actual confirmed answer exists yet. **Only theory follows.**

I think that **Yes, those students become the Knights of Ren.**

**Further speculation**: Having been betrayed by his Jedi Master (Luke), Kylo Ren turned to the most force-powerful "Master" he could find. Perhaps since the Jedi were then "extinct" (for all intents and purposes), it took him a while - but he eventually tracked down Snoke. Then Snoke, sensing that the dark side was presenting him with opportunity to acquire more power, advised Kylo Ren to recruit those students into serving the dark side under the title of "Knights of Ren". After slaughtering all of the remaining Jedi students they could find, the remaining knights went on to serve Snoke as his Praetorian Guard (the guys in the red outfits that get totally messed up by Kylo Ren and Rey).

Comment: Apparently Rian Johnson has stated [in a podcast](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/star-wars-the-last-jedi-spoiler-special) that the Praetorian guards are not the Knights of Ren: _"I guess I could’ve used them **in place of** the Praetorian guards but then it would feel like wasting them because all those guards had to die. And if Kylo had some kind of connection to them it would’ve added a complication that wouldn’t have helped the scene… Truth is, I just didn’t see a place for them in the movie."_